# Cypher: Scope of Match Statements in which Variables are Valid

Tags: variables, scope, neo4j, match, cypher

I think I have a general problem with understanding the structure of matches and the scope in which variables of the match live.

The specific piece of code where I have the problem with is this:

```
// S sentiment toward A goodFor/badFor T 
// => S sentiment toward the idea of A goodFor/badFor T

MATCH (S:A)-[:SOURCE]->(sent1:PS {type:"sentiment"})-[:TARGET]->(gfbf:E {type:"gfbf"}) , (A)-[:SOURCE]->(gfbf)-[:TARGET]->(T) , (Writer:A {type:"writer"})
// if there is some negative belief in any of the writers private state spaces that involve gfbf then inference is blocked
WHERE NOT (Writer)-[*1..]->({type:"believesTrue" , spec:FALSE})-[*1..]->(gfbf)
// if sent1 is in some private state spaces of the writer return all of these
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(Writer)-[*]->(sent1)
WITH NODES(p)[1..-1] AS ps_nodes
WHERE ALL(x IN ps_nodes[1..] WHERE LABELS(x) = "PS")

MERGE (S)-[:SOURCE]->(sent2:PS {type:"sentiment" , spec:(sent1.spec)})-[:TARGET]->(ideaOf:I {name:"ideaOf" , type:"ideaOf"})-[:TARGET]->(gfbf)

ON CREATE SET sent2.name = 
CASE sent2.spec
WHEN FALSE THEN "-S"
ELSE "+S"
END

RETURN p
```

I think it's not relevant to understand what this is for. It suffices to see the structure I assume, but basically what it does is: It looks for a subgraph where there is  path `S-->sent1-->gfbf` and also a path `A-->gfbf-->T`. If it finds that is makes a new path `A-->sent2-->ideaOf-->gfbf`, all he while setting the properties of the new nodes depending on the properties of the nodes from the match. Furthermore it looks whether it also has a path `writer-->...-->sent` where all nodes in the `...` part have label `PS`. If it finds that path then it returns this for further operations in a different part of the program.

The error I am getting is this:

```
py2neo.cypher.error.statement.InvalidSyntax: sent1 not defined (line 6, column 58 (offset: 421))
"MERGE (S)-[:SOURCE]->(sent2:PS {type:"sentiment" , spec:(sent1.spec)})-[:TARGET]->(ideaOf:I {name:"ideaOf" , type:"ideaOf"})-[:TARGET]->(g"bf)
```

Why is `sent1` no longer defined where I use it and how would I need to restructure the code to make it valid?

Answer (score 0):

sent1 in isn't in the prior WITH - change it so:

```
WITH NODES(p)[1..-1] AS ps_nodes, sent1
```